# List all Gmail History details

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function history(){
  var newResponse = Gmail.Users.History.list('email ID / 'me'');
  console.log(newResponse);

 for(var i = 0; i< newResponse.history.length; i++){
   var label = newResponse.history[i];
   console.log(JSON.stringify(label));
 }
}
```

**GOAL** I have been trying to list all my history using the above given function but it is not working. I have been trying to search for a way to make this work but I keep receiving the same error over and over: `"GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to gmail.users.history.list failed with error: Missing/invalid parameter: startHistoryId (line 13, file "GMailAPI")"`

I hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value from the method "Users.history: list" in Gmail API using Google Apps Script.

How about this answer?

### Modification points:

- In your case, it is required to include `startHistoryId` in the request of `Gmail.Users.History.list`. At the official document, `startHistoryId` is "Required".

  - I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.
- In order to retrieve `startHistoryId`, please use the method "Users: getProfile" in Gmail API.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

In order to retrieve the values from `Gmail.Users.History.list`, please run the following flow.

1. Please run the function `getStartHistoryId()`.

   - By this, `startHistoryId` is saved to PropertiesService.
2. For example, as a sample situation, please send a sample email on Gmail using browser.
3. Please run the function `history()`.

   - By this, you can retrieve the values from `Gmail.Users.History.list`.

When `history()` is run just after `getStartHistoryId()` was run, no values are returned from `Gmail.Users.History.list`. Please be careful this. The official document of `startHistoryId` is as follows.

> **startHistoryId :** Required. Returns history records after the specified startHistoryId. The supplied startHistoryId should be obtained from the historyId of a message, thread, or previous list response. History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between valid IDs. Supplying an invalid or out of date startHistoryId typically returns an HTTP 404 error code. A historyId is typically valid for at least a week, but in some rare circumstances may be valid for only a few hours. If you receive an HTTP 404 error response, your application should perform a full sync. If you receive no nextPageToken in the response, there are no updates to retrieve and you can store the returned historyId for a future request.

#### Modified script:

```
// Added: At first, please run this function and save the startHistoryId to the PropertiesService.
function getStartHistoryId() {
  var startHistoryId = Gmail.Users.getProfile('me').historyId;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("startHistoryId", startHistoryId);
}

// Modified: As the next step, please run this function.
function history() {
  var startHistoryId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("startHistoryId");
  var newResponse = Gmail.Users.History.list('me', {startHistoryId: Number(startHistoryId)});
  if ("history" in newResponse) {
    for(var i = 0; i< newResponse.history.length; i++){
      var label = newResponse.history[i];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(label));
    }
  }
}
```

- In my environment, I could confirm that `{startHistoryId: startHistoryId}` can be also used.

### Note:

- This modified script supposes that Gmail API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

### References:

- [Users.history: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)
- [Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the answer.